# MySql table creation with date

Tags: oracle

I am reviewing the code that is used to create a table, but I am having trouble deciphering it. There is no programmers comments and I am brand new to MySql.

```
(
        round( SYSDATE ) - DECODE(
            TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'Q' ),
            4,
            TO_DATE( '01-OCT-' || TO_CHAR( to_number( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' ) ) ), 'DD-MON-YYYY' ),
            TO_DATE( '01-OCT-' || TO_CHAR( to_number( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' ) - 1 ) ), 'DD-MON-YYYY' ) 
        )
```

Could someone please help walk me through this line by line so I get a better understanding of what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

That's Oracle, not MySQL.

Today, it returns

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_language = 'english';

Session altered.

SQL> select
  2    round( SYSDATE ) -
  3      DECODE(
  4        TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'Q' ),
  5        4, TO_DATE( '01-OCT-' || TO_CHAR( to_number( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' )     ) ), 'DD-MON-YYYY' ),
  6           TO_DATE( '01-OCT-' || TO_CHAR( to_number( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' ) - 1 ) ), 'DD-MON-YYYY' )
  7            ) result
  8  from dual;

    RESULT
----------
       161

SQL>
```

What does that "161" represent?

- line #2: rounds today's date:

  ```
  SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:Mi:ss';

  Session altered.

  SQL> select sysdate, round(sysdate) from dual;

  SYSDATE             ROUND(SYSDATE)
  ------------------- -------------------
  10.03.2023 22:16:57 11.03.2023 00:00:00
  ```
- line #4 returns number of today's quarter:

  ```
  SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'q') from dual;

  T
  -
  1
  ```
- line #3 compares quarter of today's date (fetched in line #4) with `4` (the 1st character in line #5):

  - if today's quarter is equal to 4, the rest of line #5 is being returned
  - otherwise, #6 line's result is returned

  As today's quarter = 1 (which is different from 4), line #6 is returned, and that's

  ```
  SQL> select TO_DATE( '01-OCT-' || TO_CHAR( to_number( TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' ) - 1 ) ), 'DD-MON-YYYY' )
    2  from dual;

  TO_DATE('01-OCT-'||
  -------------------
  01.10.2022 00:00:00
  ```

  because it concatenates 1st of October with today's year (2023) `- 1` so it returns year 2022; `01-OCT-2022` is then *converted* to `DATE` datatype (with the `TO_DATE` function)

  (If today's quarter were 4, result would've been 01-OCT-2023.)
- finally: two dates are subtracted: today's rounded date (11.03.2023) `-` result of line #6 (01.10.2022). Difference of two `date` datatype values is number of **days** between them:

  ```
  SQL> select date '2023-03-11' - date '2022-10-01' as final_result from dual;

  FINAL_RESULT
  ------------
           161
  ```

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The code calculates the number of days between the most recent 1st October and the current date.

If could be written in a much simpler form (and without relying on a specific language) using:

```sql
ROUND(SYSDATE) - ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,3), 'YY'), -3)
```

However, `ROUND` would round times towards the nearest midnight and any times in the afternoon would round to the next day and I would assume that that is incorrect behaviour and you would want to `TRUNC`ate the date rather than rounding.

```sql
TRUNC(SYSDATE) - ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,3), 'YY'), -3)
```

For example, since it is afternoon:

```sql
SELECT ROUND(SYSDATE) - ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,3), 'YY'), -3)
         AS rounded_days_since_1st_oct,
       TRUNC(SYSDATE) - ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,3), 'YY'), -3)
         AS days_since_1st_oct
FROM   DUAL
```

Outputs:

| ROUNDED_DAYS_SINCE_1ST_OCT | DAYS_SINCE_1ST_OCT |
| --- | --- |
| 161 | 160 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h9MJlujj)